# QSettings - reading INI file

Tags: c++, qt, ini, qsettings

I create an INI file and then try to read it. There is no compile errors and the file is there but I'm not receiving any data in my QStringList

```
QFile checkConfig(configPath);
    if(checkConfig.exists())
    {
        QSettings* settings = new QSettings(configPath, QSettings::IniFormat);
        settings->beginGroup("General");
        const QStringList childKeys = settings->childKeys();
        QStringList values;
        foreach (const QString &childKey, childKeys)
            values << settings->value(childKey).toString();
        settings->endGroup();
        QString test = configPath;
        int a;
    }
```

this is my INI file

```
[General]
InterviewPath=C:/1234
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem stemmed from the INI not being created correctly.

```
QSettings settings(configPath, QSettings::IniFormat);
    settings.beginGroup("/General");
    settings.setValue("/InterviewPath", interviewPath);
    settings.endGroup();
```

Comment: @Volomike its been so long, I dont remember sorry friend =)

Answer (score 2):

Do not use settings->beginGroup("General");

```
        QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    QSettings* settings = new QSettings("d:/a.ini", QSettings::IniFormat);
  //  settings->beginGroup("General");
    const QStringList childKeys = settings->childKeys();
    QStringList values;
    foreach (const QString &childKey, childKeys)
        values << settings->value(childKey).toString();
   // settings->endGroup();
    qDebug()<<values;
```

Comment: See content of attached .ini file. There are group "General".

Comment: it doesn't appear to grab the value of the key but it does return half of the key pair

Answer (score 2):

```
   QSettings* settings = new QSettings(configPath, QSettings::IniFormat);
   settings.sync(); // !!!
```

If your first call will be run after some events processing - then all will be ok. But if you want to directly open .ini file and use it in same method - then you should force syncronization. Read qt docs for additional info about sync().